# Filemaker PHP getfield as URL using <a href>

Tags: php, filemaker

I am trying to return a list of projects which I can do via the following code: (this is part of a larger if statement, that is why the dangling { bracket in the foreach line)

```
foreach ($r->getRecords() as $project){
        echo $project->getField('Project_Name') .'<br />';
```

That returns the list just as it should.  I am now trying to link each of the returned $project variable to a URL (each project will re-direct to another page showing project details.) Here is what I have tried.

```
foreach ($r->getRecords() as $project){
        echo '<a href="project_detail.php">' $project->getField('Project_Name') '</a>' .'<br />';
```

That returned a syntax error on the

```
foreach ($r->getRecords() as $project){
        echo $project->getField("<a href='project_detail.php'>'Project_Name'</a>") .'<br />';
```

Any advice or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to link to a project you're going to need to pass in some kind of identifier for the link so that your `project_detail.php` file knows what project record to find. In the code below I make the assumption that the id field of the project record id called `id`.

```
// Please never use single letter variables in your code.
foreach ($result->getRecords() as $project){
    $projectId   = $project->getField('id'); // This should be whatever primary key field (serial number field) you define for your project
    $projectName = $project->getField('Project_Name');

    echo "<a href='project_detail.php?id=$projectId'>$projectName</a><br>";
}
```

If you write the data you need into variables first, you can then use a **double quote** string to construct the link and use the variable names without having to concatenate everything. You end up with a couple of extra lines of code but your link string is way more readable.

Now your `project_detail.php` file can use the project id value to find the project record:

```
$projectId = $_GET['id'];

$findRequest = $fm->newFindCommand('project_layout_name');
$findRequest->addFindCriterion('id', $projectId);
$findResult = $findRequest->execute();
....
```

Comment: This fixed my issue thank you so much.  One note: if I try to use $result instead of $r then I get nothing returned on the page.  Do I have to change every $r to $result to get it to return normally?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to replace every instance of `$r` so that all of your variable names match. In general you want to use variable names that describe the data that they're meant to hold. It's not a rule, but it's good practice. If you leave your variable named `$r` then you or anyone else has to *assume* what the variable is  holding rather than knowing. That said, if you have a variable that holds generally known data it's ok, e.g. `$fm` for the FileMaker object is fine because FileMaker is commonly abbreviated fm, or for a iterator in a loop `$i` is commonly understood to stand for iterator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
echo '<a href="project_detail.php">' $project->getField('Project_Name') '</a>' .'<br />';

Missing Concatenating (.)

echo '<a href="project_detail.php">'.$project->getField('Project_Name').'</a><br />';
```